# Android: Set TextView's typeface to NORMAL brings crash

Tags: android, typeface

I have a toggleButton. If the button is checked I set a textView's typeface to BOLD and if not checked it should be NORMAL. After I set it to NORMAL I check if it's bold with the isBold() method. There comes the nullpointerexception. 
Weird is: If I set it to ITALIC or BOLD there is no exception...

```
        if(toggleButton.isChecked()){
          textViews.get(selectedId).setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        }else{
          textViews.get(selectedId).setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL); //When I set it here to ITALIC everything works fine
        }
        //Check where error occurs
        TextView textView=textViews.get(selectedId);
        Typeface typeface=textView.getTypeface();
        boolean isBold=typeface.isBold();       //Here is the nullpointerexception
        System.out.println("isBold "+isBold);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typeface is indeed `NULL`, as you explicitly set it, so `getTypeface` returns `NULL`. You can do a slight change to make it work:

```
 if(toggleButton.isChecked()){
     textViews.get(selectedId).setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD, Typeface.BOLD);
 }else{
     textViews.get(selectedId).setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.NORMAL); //When I set it here to ITALIC everything works fine
 }
```

`Typeface.DEFAULT` and `Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD` are the default typefaces for normal and bold styles. This way `getTypeface` won't return NULL and you'll explicitly set the -default- typeface.